# Can't use Graphviz as a library in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, graphviz

I'm attempting to build the example "demo.c" from [graphviz documentation](https://graphviz.org/docs/library/) in Visual Studio 2022.

But when I try to compile the code, I am receiving the following two build errors:

> 1 unresolved externals, unresolved external symbol Agdirected

Agdirected is used in line 33 from "demo.c".

I have already added the include directory in the project's Property Pages, along with the necessary libraries in the Link Library Dependencies.

> Additional Include Directories: C:\Program Files\Graphviz\include\graphviz;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

> Additional Library Directorys: C:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

> Additional Dependencies: gvc.lib;gvc++.lib;cgraph.lib;cgraph++.lib;cdt.lib

Comment: The problem is in 64 bit compiler while the graphviz is 32 bit.

Comment: I had downloaded the 64-bit version from the website. However, now I ended up installing the 32-bit version and received the same error. I used the installer for both versions.
I also tried using the *.lib files from the ZIP version and received 'unresolved external symbol _Agdirected' as error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's a linker error, not compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define "GVDLL" before including gvc.h,
e.g.:

```
#define GVDLL
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>
...
```

Alternatively, you can add this define under "C/C++ - Preprocessor - Preprocessor Definitions" in your Visual Studio project.

I've got the same error as you and adding that preprocessor directive solved it in my case.